# dot syntax within an object of an array

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I have a custom object with the property 'ago'.

If I want to acces this property, I can use

```
object.age
```

If I now have an array of custom objects that have the property 'age', I would expect to be able to access the age like this (fifth object in the array)

```
myArray[4].age
```

but it works only in the bracket syntax

```
[myArray[4] age]
```

Is there no dot syntax available within arrays, or what am i missung?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dot syntax only when the compiler knows what class the object is:

```
id x = array[4]; 
float age = [x age];

SomeClass *x = array[4];
float age = x.age;
```

Please note that the first version is pretty risky. I have had to deal with legacy code in one project that looked something like this:

```
NSString *recommendation = [[[[[[[dataArray 
    objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] mainPerson] friends] 
    objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] recommendations] 
    objectAtIndex:0] title];
```

Each object there was a custom class. Each message is a potential crash. A nightmare to debug.

My advice: don't go there and take advantage of the strong typing support of the compiler.

**Better write a few lines more code and make sure to not fire random messages at unpredictable and unverified objects.**

Comment: I still think my answer is better than the one you accepted. Making dot notation possible via a cast is even more convoluted and irresponsible than just firing messages at objects.

Comment: @Mundi Making dot notation possible via a cast is no worse than assigning an object from an array to a pointer of a specific class (`SomeClass *x = array[4];` in your example). You still have no guarantees that the object is of the type your assigning it to. The only difference with the cast is that it can be done all on the same line. NOTE, I'm not suggesting the cast is any better, but it's no worse either. It all ends up being a message to the object anyway. Your solution and mine are just equivalent ways for the compiler to accept the dot notation.

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C doesn't have strongly typed collections, as it's a dynamically typed language. Therefore, the compiler cannot know the type of objects stored in a collection (array in this case), which is why you cannot use the dot syntax. The error the compiler gives you is `Property 'age' is not found on object of type 'id'`, which tells you the object returned from the collection is of type `id`.

If you want to use dot notation you'll have to include a cast:

`NSUInteger age = ((MyClass *) myArray[4]).age;`

Besides being a bit ugly, I would only do this if you are 100% sure that you know that the array will only contain objects of type `MyClass`.

Answer (score -4):

[[myArray objectAtIndex:4]age]

Comment: This may answer the question, but it is advisable to add a bit of description with the answer. Otherwise there is every chance that you answer might get deleted as "Very Low Quality".

Comment: He is already ok with sending the message. He wants to use dot syntax.

Comment: I don't really agree with Krishnabhadra's view on short answers. I think answers should be as short as possible, but no shorter.